# How to determine if Android app version is pro or lite from an Activity in a Library Project?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-activity

I'm currently changing my free version to a lite+pro combo by using a library to hold all of the important code, including my activities. Essentially what I plan to do is have a one-line in the code check if the app running is the pro or lite version, and modify the app's appearance and functionality accordingly. I'm just not sure what that line should be.

So say my activity being launched from the manifest is `com.example.myapp.lib.MainActivity`, and my two packages are `com.example.myapp` and `com.example.myapp.pro`. What is a function I can call to check what the currently running package is?

It occurs to me I could possibly do this through a `preference.xml` file in each app. Would that be better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to call Activity.getPackageName from your activity

Comment: That was exactly as simple as I had been hoping. Thanks!